# Geoserver Custom CRS IAU_Moon_2000

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver, gdal

I am trying to setup a custom basemap using a GTiff in the [IAU's Moon2000 projection](http://spatialreference.org/ref/iau2000/30101/) (30100 or 30101).  The basemap image was originally created through gdal_merge and gdalinfo returns the expected, human-readable WKT CRS information.

As per the geoserver documentation, I then used gdal_retile.py to automatically generate my pyramids and the accompanying directory structure.  This was then moved into /data-dir/data.  A new workspace, for organization, and new store were created.  I am able to add the basemap "layer", using the pyramid plugin, but the CRS defaulted a UTM zone (18N).

As per the geoserver documentation, I then edited the epgs.properties file and added the single line WKT from the link above.  Through the geoserver web administration tool, I can see that the CRS was successfully added, but the wkt is empty.  See the screenshot below.

I suspect that I now need to go in an manually add both a custom datum and spheroid.  Is this the case?  If so does anyone have documentation of this process?  Has anyone gotten planetary data (any planetary body) added to geoserver as a basemap?

The end goal is to server the tiled basemap as a WMS to openlayers.

[image: Geoserver webUI capture]